# 'IBM437' is not a supported encoding name from ZipFile Read Method

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-phone-8.1, zip

I have a problem when my code execute this using:

```
using (ZipFile archive = ZipFile.Read(File))    //<== Crash Here!
{
    foreach (ZipEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        entry.Extract(UnZipFolder.Name.ToString(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);   
    }
}
```

Crash when ZipFile try to read my File that it's a string and contains, sincrofit.zip then crash and throw this exception:

> 'System.ArgumentException' Additional information: 'IBM437' is not a
>   supported encoding name.

Comment: The encoding name is plain "437".  Send the file back, you don't want it.

Comment: And why don't want it? :O

Comment: If you are using .net core, this should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix

Answer (score 49):

In Visual Studio:

1. Open Package Manager Console and type in **Install-Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages -Version 4.4.0**. Change the version number appropriately.
2. Add this line to your code:                 **Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);**
3. Attach the necessary directive if required.