# 'IBM437' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: .net, ionic-framework, .net-core, zip

I'm having an error of this,

```
'IBM437' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name
at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(String name)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile..ctor(String fileName)
at ConnexusDomain.AppBridge.DecompressFile(String zipfilename, String userID)
console-via-logger.js (173,15)
```

This occur when my code reaches this line of code

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" + zipfilename + ".zip");
```

I already tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068626/2637261) solution. However I'm having an error of this when it reaches the **Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): WinRTError: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at ConnexusDomain.AppBridge.DecompressFile(String zipfilename, String userID)
WinRTError: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at ConnexusDomain.AppBridge.DecompressFile(String zipfilename, String userID)
```

I'm coding with Ionic Framework and bridge some of the functionalities with C# (.Net Core 2.0).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I see a *WinRTError*... perhaps that package isn't compatible with WinRT...

Comment: @xanatos So the solution of the other question I linked out is not valid to my problem?

Comment: Sadly haven't ever programmed for WinRT, so I don't know...

Comment: you can refer this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659499/epplus-error-reading-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659499/epplus-error-reading-file)