# how do I save an excel file with eeplus?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am trying to create and excel file using .NET Console App C#. Im using OfficeOpenXML (EPPLUS) but every time I tried to save it it raise an error

ERROR
"IBM437 is not supported encoding name"

So this is the code I wrote

```
var workbook = new ExcelPackage();

ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PM Bonus");
worksheet.View.FreezePanes(-1, 5);

SetExcelReportHeaders(worksheet);
SetReportExcelData(worksheet);

workbook.Save("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Freeze or Split Panes.xlsx");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Slashes go the other way.  Try `workbook.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Freeze or Split Panes.xlsx");` with the leading escape character.

Comment: Hey! thanks, sorry for the delayed answer, it didn't worked, it raise the same error :(

Comment: Try ['IBM437' is not a supported encoding name from ZipFile Read Method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25993251/719186) or [EPPlus error reading file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44659499/719186)